# Texture Baking issue - Not using correct UVs

Tags: uv, baking, error

I have been having this maddening issue lately which I cannot for the life of me seem to fix. Essentially I have a small environment with several objects that I have projected a bunch of painted texture onto from the camera view. I now wish to bake all of these separate images onto a single texture sheet, so I am baking them one by one onto a new image texture. I have one UV channel with the projected UVs and another to use for the baked atlas sheet.

All of the objects seem to work fine apart from one which keeps returning this strange error. When I bake, it keeps the UVs from the projected UV channel with some of the new UVs but not others. Any idea what could be happening here? Yes, I have "clear image" checked and I am making sure to have the correct image selected in the shader editor. [image: Painted texture] [image: Projected UVs][image: Baked texture][image: Baked UVs]

Comment: Have you used a UV map node for the Image Texture that you are going to bake? If not, which UV is enabled for rendering in the UV list (camera icon) on the Object Data Properties tab? I'm not sure if the selected list entry there is relevant for baking and would use a *UV Map* node. This makes it clear which UV map is being used.

Comment: Yeah I did try that as well- still didn't fix the issue and still wouldn't explain why I didn't have to do that for the other objects... The projected uv map is enabled with the camera icon while the baked UV map is highlighted on data properties. Again, the setup that worked for all the other objects in the scene.

Comment: In the end I figured out a workaround. I had to select all of the faces in the object, separate selection, and the new object that was created baked correctly. Still no idea what was causing this problem in the first place but hopefully this will be useful for someone.